# getJSON internal event encountering Reference Error on passed-in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html, asynchronous

I have a method that populates a table using a JSON call to a MVC controller, as below:

```
pub.PopulateTable = function (args) {
    var page = 1,
        // ...variables snipped...
        OnRowClicked;

    // Unpack arguments...
    if (args != null) {
        // ...details snipped...

        OnRowClicked = args.OnRowClicked;
    }

    // Build path...
    path = path + controller + '/' + action + '/';
    if (actionId != null && actionId != '') {
        path = path + actionId + '/';
    }
    path = path + page;

    $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        if (data.Values.length > 0) {
            // Clear table body, then inject list...
            $tableBody.html('');
            $.tmpl($template, data.Values).appendTo($tableBody);

            // ...snip various instructions, for brevity...

            // Add on-click returning...
            $('tr').click(function () {
                var $row = $(this),
                    rowData = {};

                rowData.SomeProperty = $row.children('#IdColumn').val();

                $modalDialog.modal('hide');
                OnRowClicked(rowData);  // Problem!!!
            });
        } else {
            $tableBody.html("<tr><td colspan=2>No entries...</td></tr>");
        }
    });
```

Perhaps it's because getJSON is an asynchronous operation, but the OnRowClicked() method that is passed in via the method argument object is encountering a Reference Error when it tries to use the following (simple) method that is passed into it:

```
function textFieldRowClickHandler(rowData) {
    $myTextFieldHere.val(rowData.SomeProperty);
}
```

When I open up the dialog (which causes PopulateTable to run and bind the events inside it), and select a record (thus firing the click event off), I keep getting a reference error because rowData.SomeProperty is undefined, even though the callback is binding a click event to every tr tag that, when it is clicked, closes the dialog, takes the values, builds an object, and passes that to the given method.

As noted above - I know that getJSON is an Async operation, and that's where I think my problems are arising - I'm not familiar with the Async paradigm.  What am I doing wrong, exactly?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, other than rowData doesn't have a `SomeProperty` property, all it has is `ID`

Comment: eep!  Good catch!  But I mean SomeProperty, not ID.  EDIT: Updated the code; I did make sure that my code has variables set up correctly, just to rule that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the OnRowClicked method when called, doesn't have the context set correctly.

you can use:

```
OnRowClicked = args.OnRowClicked.bind(args);
```

or

```
OnRowClicked = $.proxy(args.OnRowClicked,args);
```

so it should look like:

```
pub.PopulateTable = function (args) {
var page = 1,
    // ...variables snipped...
    OnRowClicked;

// Unpack arguments...
if (args != null) {
    // ...details snipped...

    OnRowClicked = args.OnRowClicked.bind(args);
}
```